# How to cache node_modules on Docker build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, continuous-integration, tutum

I've been trying for some time to cache `node_modules` on a Docker build. I've tried several approaches including the one [here](http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/), but without success.

My main reason to cache is because it takes **30+** minutes to build my image, which is way too much.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# This image will be based on the oficial nodejs docker image
FROM node:4.2.1

RUN npm install -g jspm@0.17.0-beta.7 && \
    npm install -g gulp && \
    npm install -g tsd

# Use changes to package.json to force Docker not to use the cache
# when we change our application's nodejs dependencies:
ADD package.json /src/package.json
RUN cd /src && npm install

# Put all our code inside that directory that lives in the container
ADD . /src

# Set in what directory commands will run
WORKDIR /src

# Install dependencies
RUN cd /src && \
    tsd reinstall -so && \
    jspm install && \
    gulp build -p

# Tell Docker we are going to use this port
EXPOSE 3000

# The command to run our app when the container is run
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-production"]
```

I do not have a `.dockerignore` file. I added one before but it still didn't cache my `node_modules`.

So, **how to I cache my node_modules**? Feel free to suggest modifications to the `Dockerfile`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is the root of the error, but try to specify the destination **folder** in the *ADD* command and not the destination **file**.

```
ADD package.json /src
```

Moreover, you can use *COPY* instead of *ADD* (*ADD* can work with url and archives but you don't need it here).

You can also specify your *working directory* earlier in the file.

Try with this code :

```
    # This image will be based on the official nodejs docker image
    FROM node:4.2.1
    
    RUN npm install -g jspm@0.17.0-beta.7 && \
        npm install -g gulp && \
        npm install -g tsd

    # Set in what directory commands will run
    WORKDIR /src
    
    # Use changes to package.json to force Docker not to use the cache
    # when we change our application’s nodejs dependencies:
    COPY package.json ./

    RUN npm install
    
    # Put all our code inside that directory that lives in the container
    COPY . ./
    
    # Install dependencies
    RUN tsd reinstall -so && \
        jspm install && \
        gulp build -p
    
    # Tell Docker we are going to use this port
    EXPOSE 3000
    
    # The command to run our app when the container is run
    CMD ["npm", "run", "start-production"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still takes 25 minutes to build the image. Also, from the logs I can see it is not using the cached folders. I have an automated build, could that be a problem? @haverchuck

Comment: Yes, the automated build seems to not use cache. Probably because the image are build on a random machine that doesn't have the necessary cache.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that fact, I had a hard time finding this somewhere in the docs. I'll try a non-automated build then!